# Jest test call to process.exit in endless setInterval(,0) using Singletons

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, setinterval, ts-jest

The original project has a class which has some long running work. This is done on in processes on servers, which occasionally get `SIGINT`s to stop. I want to persist the state once that happens. This is why I put the work into an `setInterval(,0)` wrapper, for the event loop get the Interrupts. This would not work in a `while(true)`-loop.

Now I want to test, if the Subject works correctly - in this case: Validating the input.
A MWE can be found [here](https://github.com/dderjoel/mwe-jest-setinterval).

the work is done in `subject.class.ts`:

```js
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";
import { tmpdir } from "os";
import { join, basename } from "path";
export default class Subject {
  private counter = 0;
  public doWork(inputdata: string): void {
    if (!inputdata) {
      process.exit(100); // exit if no input was given
    }
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
      if (this.counter > 10e2) {
        process.exit(0);
      }
      if (this.counter % 10e1 == 0) {
        console.log(this.counter);
      }
    }, 0);
  }
  public persist(): void {
    const data = JSON.stringify(this.counter);
    const path = join(tmpdir(), basename(__filename));
    writeFileSync(path, data);
    console.log(`Persisted to ${path}`);
  }
}
```

I create a `new Subject`, set the interrupt handlers and call the `subj.doWork("peanut")` method to start the work in `main.ts`:

```js
import Subject from "./subject.class";

const subj = new Subject();

process.on("exit", (exitcode: number) => {
  if (exitcode == 0) {
    process.stdout.write(`\nDone Success. :)\n`);
  } else {
    process.stderr.write(`\nDone with code: ${exitcode}\n`);
  }
  subj.persist();
  process.stdout.write("exiting.");
  process.exit(exitcode);
});

process.on("SIGINT", (signal: "SIGINT") => {
  process.stdout.write(`\ncaught ${signal}`);
  process.exit(13);
});

subj.doWork("peanut");
```

All that works file. To test the call to `process.exit`, I create a `jest.spyOn` on it, which calls the `done`-function from the `it` in `tests/subject.test.ts`

```js
import Subject from "../src/subject.class";

describe("subject test suite", () => {
  jest.spyOn(console, "log").mockImplementation();
  it("should exit on invalid input", (done) => {
    const spyExit = jest.spyOn(process, "exit").mockImplementation(((
      nu: number
    ) => {
      expect(nu).toEqual(100);
      spyExit.mockRestore();
      done();
    }) as any);

    expect(() => new Subject().doWork("")).not.toThrow();
  });
  it.skip("should work on valid input", (done) => {
    const spyExit = jest.spyOn(process, "exit").mockImplementation(((
      nu: number
    ) => {
      expect(nu).toEqual(0); // does not matter because it is not checked anyway
      spyExit.mockRestore();
      done();
    }) as any);

    expect(() => new Subject().doWork("valid")).not.toThrow();
  });
});
```

The problem is, that `Jest` exits before `done` is called in the first `it`; `Jest` then complains on the command line that logs have been attempted to be written. When un`skip`ing the second case, the first one works, because `Jest` is still alive. However, the `expect.toEqual(0);` is also never called. This `0` can be any number and the test still does not fail (it just prints to the console, that `process.exit` called with "0", but with a wrong line number).

How can I test this Subject's work method?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple things to say:

1. Because `process.exit()` is no longer exiting (cause it's mock'ed), the interval must be cleared and we need to return, when `process.exit()` was called.
2. In Jest tests the Timer can/should/need to be faked. (see [Jest Documentation on Timer-Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks))
3. Depending on the test setup (I used `singleton` patterns in the real project) it was helpful to have one test file per `test`/`it` to ensure they don't collide with the singleton-instances. It seems that there is one thread per file (and they are then ran in parallel).
4. Try `jest --runInBand`.

`subject.class.ts`:

```js
if (!inputdata) {
  return process.exit(100); // note 'return'
}
const id = setInterval(()=> // save interval-id
  this.counter++;
  if (this.counter > 10e2) {
    clearInterval(id);      // clear before exit'ing
    return process.exit(0); // note 'return'
  }
  if (this.counter % 10e1 == 0) {
    console.log(this.counter);
  }
}, 0);
```

`tests/subject.test.ts`:

```js
beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
});
afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
});


// and in the test then run the Timers
expect(() => new Subject().doWork("")).not.toThrow();
jest.runAllTimers();
```